# Python Bokeh getting error in adding colorbar to plot

Tags: python, bokeh, colorbar

I have following code (part of it). I am trying to add a color bar for the palette used in the plot. I am successful in getting the plot but not he colorbar.

```
from bokeh.palettes import Turbo256
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d,Label, 
LabelSet,ColumnDataSource,LinearColorMapper,ColorBar

x = Combined_Data_Air[X1]
y = Combined_Data_Air[Y1a]
z = Combined_Data_Air['xxxxxxx']

# X1 and Y1a are Pandas column names.

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict( x = x,y=y,z = z))
cmap = linear_cmap(field_name='z', palette="Turbo256",low = 0, high = 30)
s1.circle(x= 'x', y ='y', source=source,color=cmap, legend_label=Y1a,size=2)


color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=cmap,location = 'right')
```

in the last line of code I get following error.

*ValueError: failed to validate ColorBar(id='1074', ...).color_mapper: expected an instance of type ColorMapper, got {'field': 'z', 'transform': LinearColorMapper(id='1054', ...)} of type dict*

I can get the plot based on palette if I do not try to add the color bar.

Comment: `linear_cmap` is a convenience for specifying color mappers field specifications, i.e you'd use `fill_color=linear_cmap(...)`. But the color bar needs just the color mapper itself. To do this manually, you'd need to construct a `LinearColorMapper` instance to pass.  But recent versions  have `construct_color_bar` that will just generate an appropriately configured color bar from the glyph automatically. See the docs: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/basic/annotations.html#color-bars

Comment: If I use following this code color_bar = s1.construct_color_bar(padding=1) then it gives following error: AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'construct_color_bar' to Figure, possible attributes are above, align, aspect_ratio, aspect_scale, background, background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, below, ....

Comment: Please study the example more closely. `construct_color_bar` is a method of the glyph renderer, not of the entire figure.

Comment: I used following lines and it seems to be working.         color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=LinearColorMapper(palette="Turbo256",low = 0, high = 30),location = 'right')       s1.add_layout(color_bar, 'right').       I will still study and try the contruct_color_bar.